# Example of docListToSolrDocumentList

Tags: solr, lucene, converters, solr4

Can someone give an example of [this](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_3_1/solr-core/org/apache/solr/util/SolrPluginUtils.html#docListToSolrDocumentList%28org.apache.solr.search.DocList,%20org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher,%20java.util.Set,%20java.util.Map%29)

for solr 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best place to look for examples for JUnit Test Cases.
Check for the [SolrPluginUtilsTest.java](http://www.massapi.com/source/apache-solr-3.3.0/solr/src/test/org/apache/solr/util/SolrPluginUtilsTest.java.html) for the example of this function.